# Как вывести значение из textarea в js

Tags: javascript, html

Работою с API SpeechSynthesis, хочу сделать так, чтобы из textarea брался вводимый текст пользователем и с помощью button прослушивался, вопрос в чём моя ошибка?

```js
var text = document.getElementById('text');
var msg = text.value;
text.value ="";
var synth = window.speechSynthesis;
var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(msg);

function talk() {
    speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Читалка</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Введите текст:</p>
    <textarea name="text" id="text" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br>
    <button onclick="talk()">Прослушать</button>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function talk() {
  var text = document.getElementById('text');
  var msg = text.value;
  //text.value = "";
  //var synth = window.speechSynthesis;
  var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(msg);
  if (document.getElementById("russian").checked)
    utterance.lang = "ru-RU";
  speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
}
```

```html
<p>Введите текст:</p>
<textarea name="text" id="text" cols="30" rows="5">
A B C D E

Наша Таня громко плачет
</textarea><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="russian" />Русский язык<label>
<button onclick="talk()">Прослушать</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо,ПОНЕЛ!!

Answer (score 0):

Функция talk находится в области видимости недоступной из html.
Для её вызова необходимо определить функцию как член document:

```js
var text = document.getElementById('text');
var msg = text.value;
text.value ="";
var synth = window.speechSynthesis;
var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(msg);

document.talk = function() {
    alert('ok');
    speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Читалка</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Введите текст:</p>
    <textarea name="text" id="text" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br>
    <button onclick="talk()">Прослушать</button>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```